# What is the correct pronunciation of Nagios?

Tags: nagios

I've puzzled and debated over this for a while, so it's time to ask the community.  What is the correct accepted pronunciation of *Nagios*, or at least the most common pronunciation?  [This topic is addressed in the project's FAQ](http://community.nagios.org/2007/02/20/nagios-pronunciation/), but the linked .mp3 of the pronunciation has been missing for some time.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[From the Nagios knowledge base FAQ:](https://support.nagios.com/knowledge-base/view-faq/?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&catid=35&faq_id=3&expand=false&showdesc=true)

> I pronounce Nagios as:
>
> nah-ghee-ose
>
> At least I think that's how I pronounce it (damn phonetic spelling)... The  "Na" sounds like "Nah", "gi" sounds like the first part of "geese", and "os" sounds like the last part of "verbose". You can pronounce it however the heck you'd like.
>
> Alternative pronounciations vary. One that I liked is "nachos". Mmmmmm.... nachos.

*Answer originally linked to an mp3 audio file which contained the pronunciation as spoken by Ethan, the author of Nagios. **File is no longer hosted by Nagios**.*

Comment: For those that don't want to listen (or in case the linked file disappears) - it's pronounced with a hard 'g', as in the word "geek".  So pronounce na-gee-os as if the middle syllable is the word geek without the "k".

Comment: Though the original audio file is no longer accessible, the Nagios YouTube channel (nagiosvideo) pronounces it this way as well.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure but I always use Nag-ee-os

Comment: Hard 'g' or soft?

Comment: I use a hard 'g'. I just found a second person using a soft 'g' which is how I found this page.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard nah-gee-ohs.  That's what I've heard.

Comment: Hard 'g' or soft?

Comment: the g is the same as in .gif